# URL Fragment and 302 redirects

Tags: redirect, fragment-identifier, http-redirect

It's well known that the URL fragment (the part after the `#`) is not sent to the server.

I do wonder though how fragments work when a server redirect (via HTTP status 302 and `Location:` header) is involved.

My question is really two-fold:

1. If the original URL had a fragment (`/original.php#foo`), and a redirect is made to `/new.php`, does the fragment part of the original URL simply get lost? Or does it sometimes get applied to the new URL? 
   Will the new URL ever be `/new.php#foo` in this case?
2. Regardless of the original URL, if the server redirects to a new URL with a fragment (`/new.php#foo`), will the fragment get "honored"? Or does the server really have no business interfering with the fragment at all -- and will the browser therefore ignore it by simply going to `/new.php`??

Comment: Here you can find spec by W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/cuap#uri clause 4.1. the fragment should be preserved on redirect.

Comment: @Marcin: W3C TAG suggest differently: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2010OctDec/0504.html. Related question: [Is a 302 Redirect to relative URL valid, or invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250259/is-a-302-redirect-to-relative-url-valid-or-invalid)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

**Update 2022-09-22**:

[RFC 9110/STD 97 HTTP Semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110) (which obsoletes 7231 (and others)), has been published as an INTERNET STANDARD in June 2022. The wording in the newly numbered [Section 10.2.2 Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-10.2.2) stays the same as before/below.

**Update 2014-Jun-27**:

[RFC 7231, Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), has been published as a PROPOSED STANDARD. From the [Changelog](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#appendix-B):

> The syntax of the Location header field has been changed to allow all
> URI references, including relative references and fragments, along
> with some clarifications as to when use of fragments would not be
> appropriate.  (Section 7.1.2)

The important points from [Section 7.1.2. Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2):

> If the Location value provided in a 3xx (Redirection) response does
> not have a fragment component, a user agent MUST process the
> redirection as if the value inherits the fragment component of the URI
> reference used to generate the request target (i.e., the redirection
> inherits the original reference's fragment, if any).

> For example, a
> GET request generated for the URI reference
> "http://www.example.org/~tim" might result in a 303 (See Other)
> response containing the header field:
>
> ```
> Location: /People.html#tim
> ```
>
> which suggests that the user agent redirect to
> "http://www.example.org/People.html#tim"
>
> Likewise, a GET request generated for the URI reference
> "http://www.example.org/index.html#larry" might result in a 301 (Moved
> Permanently) response containing the header field:
>
> ```
> Location: http://www.example.net/index.html
> ```
>
> which suggests that the user agent redirect to
> "http://www.example.net/index.html#larry", preserving the original
> fragment identifier.

This should clearly answer your questions.

**Update END**

this is an open (not specified) issue with the [current HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). it is addressed in 2 issues of the [IETF httpbis working group](http://www.ietf.org/dyn/wg/charter/httpbis-charter.html):

- [#6: *Fragments allowed in Location*](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/6)
- [#43: *Fragment combination / precedence during redirects*](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/43)

#6 allows fragments in the `Location` header. #43 says this:

> I just tested this with various browsers.

> - Firefox and Safari use the fragment in the location header.
> - Opera uses the fragment from the source URI, when present, otherwise the fragment from the redirect location
> - IE (8) ignores the fragment in the location URI, thus will use the fragment from the source URI, when present

> Proposal:

> "Note: the behavior when fragment identifiers from the original URI and the redirect need to be combined is undefined; current User Agents indeed differ on what fragment takes precedence."

> [...]

> It appears that IE8 *does* use the fragment idenfitier from `Location` (the behavior I saw might be limited to localhost).

> Thus we seem to have consistent behavior for Safari/IE/Firefox/Chrome (just tested), in that the fragment from the Location header gets used, no matter what the original URI was.

> I therefore change my proposal to document *that* as expected behavior.

this leads to the most browser compatible and future proof (because this issue will eventually get standardized) answer to your question:

**A:** fragments from original URLs get discarded.

**B:** fragments from the `Location` header are honored.

Comment: I had forgotten about some "rewrite" rules I set in HTTP servers, which were probably implemented as 301 redirect. As a consequence IE kept losing fragment identifier because when you have multiple redirects, the fragments set by the first redirect becomes part of the *source* URI in the second.

Comment: opera 12.12 honors the fragment in the location header when present.

Comment: On the current versions of both Chrome and Firefox: **A** is not true. On the current version of Firefox: **B** is not true. At the moment, if you have to use hashes (e.g., using Backbone's routing) it seems that javascript-based redirection is your only real option.

Comment: The quoted block seems to contradict itself. First it says "IE (8) ignores the fragment in the location URI, thus will use the fragment from the source URI, when present", then later it says "It appears that IE8 does use the fragment identifier from Location". Is the first referring to something different from the second?

Comment: B is not true for Chome 45.0.2454.85. B is true for Firefox 40.0.3.

Answer (score 48):

Safari 5 and IE9 and below drop the original URI's fragment if a HTTP/3xx redirect occurs. If the Location header on the response specifies a fragment, it is used.

IE10+, Chrome 11+, Firefox 4+, and Opera will all "reattach" the original URI's fragment after following a 3xx redirection.

Test page: http://www.webdbg.com/test/redir/fragment/.

See further discussion of this issue at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/17/url-fragments-and-redirects-anchor-hash-missing.aspx

Comment: Actually IE10 still behaves differently from latest Firefox and Chrome versions. It does seem to preserve the fragment from the source URL in case of a simple redirect. And if the redirect `Location` contains a fragment, it will keep it correctly. **But** if a redirected `Location` with a fragment goes through another 3xx redirect, it will inexplicably ignore the fragment from the first redirection, which is not consistent with the 2 previous behaviors. Chrome and Firefox consistently preserve it.

Comment: I've confirmed that you're correct. See the final test link on this page: http://www.webdbg.com/test/redir/fragment/

Comment: It makes sense to drop the #fragment from any previous URL in a chain of redirects. You are likely going to a page where that anchor no longer applies/exists.

Answer (score 12):

Just to let you know, here you can find proper spec. by w3c defining how all should behave: http://www.w3.org/TR/cuap#uri - clause 4.1 - see below:

> When a resource (URI1) has moved, an HTTP redirect can indicate its
>   new location (URI2).
>
> If URI1 has a fragment identifier #frag, then the new target that the
>   user agent should be trying to reach would be URI2#frag. If URI2
>   already has a fragment identifier, then #frag must not be appended and
>   the new target is URI2.
>
> Wrong: Most current user agents do implement HTTP redirects but do not
>   append the fragment identifier to the new URI, which generally
>   confuses the user because they end up with the wrong resource.
>
> References:
>
> HTTP redirects are described in section 10.3 of the HTTP/1.1
>   specification [RFC2616]. The required behavior is described in detail
>   in "Handling of fragment identifiers in redirected URLs" [RURL]. The
>   term "Persistent Uniform Resource Locator (PURL)" designates a URL (a
>   special case of a URI) that points to another one through an HTTP
>   redirect. For more information, refer to "Persistent Uniform Resource
>   Locators" [PURL]. Example:
>
> Suppose that a user requests the resource at
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-ruby/#changes and the server redirects the
>   user agent to http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/. Before fetching that latter
>   URI, the browser should append the fragment identifier #changes to it:
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/#changes.

Answer (score 0):

Posting similar [issue with the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917034/url-hash-fragment-removed-by-ie-after-302-redirect) faced by me.

Hope it helps to someone with the similar requirement of `preserving hash in IE` for 302 redirects.

#### Adding essential parts of the answer instead of links alone

We use `SiteMinder` authentication in our application.

I figured out that after successful authentication, `SiteMinder` is doing `302 redirection` to user requested application page by using **login form hidden variable `value`** (where it stores user requested URL `/myapp/` - `without hash fragment` since it won't be sent to the server) with name similar to `redirect`. Sample form below

[image: Sample login form]

Since `redirect` hidden variable **value** contains only `/myapp/` without hash fragment and it's a 302 redirect, the hash fragment is automatically removed by IE even before coming to our application and whatever the solutions we are trying in our application code are not working out.

IE is redirecting to `/myapp/` only and it is landing on default home page of our app `https://ourapp.com/myapp/#/home`.

Have wasted almost a day to figure out this behavior.

#### The solution is:

Have changed the **login form** hidden variable (`redirect`) **value** to hold the hash fragment by
appending `window.location.hash` along with existing value. Similar to below code

```js
$(function () {
  var $redirect = $('input[name="redirect"]');
  $redirect.val($redirect.val() + window.location.hash);
});
```

After this change, the `redirect` hidden variable is storing user requested URL value as `/myapp/#/pending/requests` and `SiteMinder` is redirecting it to `/myapp/#/pending/requests` in IE.

**The above solution is working fine in all the three browsers `Chrome, Firefox and IE`.**

Thanks to @AlexFord for the [detailed explanation and providing solution](https://chevtek.io/how-to-persist-url-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect) to this issue.