# Oauth server redirect on success or error, use HTTP redirect or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, oauth, http-redirect

All Oauth providers I've authenticated with will redirect you to a page that says something like "Thanks, redirecting you..." and uses javascript to redirect you to the supplied redirect_uri.
I would have thought it was simpler and faster to return an HTTP redirect. Why is it always done that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

302's Location header according to [HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) looks like this:

> ```
> Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```

`absoluteURI` according to [URI Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3) does not include fragment identifier. The one with the fragment is called `URI-reference`:

> ```
> URI-reference = [ absoluteURI | relativeURI ] [ "#" fragment ]
> ```

<strike>The detail is described in @levik's question: [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects). I am now learning it the hard way, but the gist is that 302 with fragment doesn't seems to work with IE8.</strike>

Using Javascript probably is more reliable way because you're suppose to pass the access tokens via fragment.

**Edit**:
I now know what happened with IE8. IE does respect the fragment identifier in Location header, but it ignores the one from source URI. My redirect URL was to `http://example.com/oauth`, which I had an automatic redirect to http**s**, `https://example.com/oauth`.

1. OAuth redirects to `http://example.com/oauth#access_token=foo`.
2. My server redirects to `https://example.com/oauth`.

Between step 1 and 2, IE8 threw away the fragment identifier, while some of the other browsers redirected to `https://example.com/oauth#access_token=foo`.

So the real answer is 302 is ok, as long as you don't use it more than once on the URL.