# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] details breakdown

Tags: php, regex

Let's say my request url:

```
http://google.com?asdgeez~user=USERNAME~hash=SECRET_TOKKEN
```

I wanna select data like $data[1], $data[2], $data[3]
It should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://google.com?asdgeez
    [1] => USERNAME
    [2] => SECRET_TOKKEN
)
```

So basically it needs to remove **~user=** and **~hash=** part.
For feature usage it helps me validate each value separately.

Any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using regexp:

```
$input = 'http://google.com?asdgeez~user=USERNAME~hash=SECRET_TOKKEN';
preg_match('/^(.*?)~\w+=(.*?)~\w+=(.*)$/', $input, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

/*
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(58) "http://google.com?asdgeez~user=USERNAME~hash=SECRET_TOKKEN"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "http://google.com?asdgeez"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "USERNAME"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "SECRET_TOKKEN"
}
*/
```

Comment: It's very good, but how about this char # ?
If it exist, array just gone :/

Comment: @Zero You didn't mention about it. In which place can it be ?

Comment: In article found answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865604/how-do-i-detect-remove-and-redirect-urls-with-a-at-the-end-in-php

It's clien-side, not server. Markink as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well...you could try it like this:

```
 $data = preg_split('#~(:?\w+=)?#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = "http://google.com?asdgeez~user=USERNAME~hash=SECRET_TOKKEN";

$str1 = explode('~user=', $uri);
$str2 = explode('~hash=', $str1[1]);

$final = array_merge($str1[0], $str2[0], $str2[1]);
```