# URL hash is persisting between redirects

Tags: http, url, redirect, hash, fragment

For some reason, non IE browsers seem to persist a URL hash (if present) when a server-side redirect is sent (using the Location header).  Example:

```
// a simple redirect using Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");
Text.aspx
```

If I visit:

```
Test.aspx#foo
```

In Firefox/Chrome, I'm taken to:

```
http://www.yahoo.com#foo
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?  I've tried this with various server side redirects in different platforms as well (all resulting in the Location header, though) and this always seems to happen.  I don't see it anywhere in the HTTP spec, but it really seems to be a problem with the browsers themselves.  The URL hash (as expected) is never sent to the server, so the server redirect isn't polluted by it, the browsers are just persisting it for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: The same issue is addressed in [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2286402/2157640). Nice answers there.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I suggest that this is the correct behaviour. The 302 and 307 status codes indicate that the resource is to be found elsewhere. `#bookmark` is a location within the resource.

Once the resource (html document) has been located it is for the browser to locate the `#bookmark` within the document.

The analogy is this: You want to look something up in a book in chapter 57, so you go to the library to get the book. But there is a note on the shelf saying the book has moved, it is now in the other building. So you go to the new location. You still want chapter 57 - it is irrelevant where you got the book.

Comment: You could however sent an explicit anchor in your `Location` header. Something like `http://www.yahoo.com#`

Comment: @Ben IE8 doesn't redirect with hash. I want it to redirect. Any ideas?

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi - did you find an answer to this, I'm also hoping there's a solution in IE? Btw IE9 doesn't either

Comment: @JustinBicknell, tested in IE10, does retain the hash on redirect.

Comment: I don't think the analogy holds up well. It's more like: You want to look something up in a book in chapter 57, but when you find chapter 57 of the book, there's a note directing you to another book. Chapter 57 of the new book is not likely to correlate with chapter 57 of the original book.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem I'm having too. On the resource I started at `#123` but the redirect sends back a page with an `autofocus`. But the `autofocus` isn't respected and it goes back to the `#123`. This is really odd behavior that the browser has implemented. The weird thing is that different form submission will strip the hash. :-(

Comment: OK, I see what I did. If I return the full URL in the action of the form it keeps the hash. But if I just have a partial URL then it removes the hash. _Very_ strange. Magic.

Answer (score 32):

This is an aspect that was not covered by previous HTTP specifications but [has been addressed in the later HTTP development](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bos-http-redirect-00):

> If the server returns a response code of 300 ("multiple choice"), 301
> ("moved permanently"), 302 ("moved temporarily") or 303 ("see
> other"), and if the server also returns one or more URIs where the
> resource can be found, then the client SHOULD treat the new URIs as
> if the fragment identifier of the original URI was added at the end.
>
> The exception is when a returned URI already has a fragment
> identifier. In that case the original fragment identifier MUST NOT be
> not added to it.

So the fragment of the original URI should also be used for the redirection URI unless it also contains a fragment.

Although this was just a draft that expired in 2000, it seems that the behavior as described above is the de-facto standard behavior among todays web browsers.

[@Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) or [@Mark Nottingham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152646/mark-nottingham) probably know more/better about this.

Comment: MUST NOT be not added to it ... poor us if that is the standard :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I have found, it doesn't seem clear what the exact behaviour should be. There are plently of people having problems with this, some of them wants to keep the bookmark through the redirect, some of them wants to get rid of it.

Different browsers handle this differently, so in practice it's not useful to rely on either behaviour.

It definitely is a browser issue. The browser never sends the bookmark part of the URL to the server, so there is nothing that the server could do to find out if there is a bookmark or not, and nothing that could be done about it reliably.

Answer (score 0):

When I put the full URL in the `action` attribute of the form, it will keep the `hash`. But when I just do the query string then it drops the hash. E.g.,

Keeps the `hash`:

`https://example.com/edit#alrighty`

```html
<form action="https://example.com/edit?ok=yes">
```

Drops the `hash`:

`https://example.com/edit`

```html
<form action="?ok=yes">
```