# Force browser to drop #hash from the URL when sending redirect

Tags: java, http, url, web, jetty

I am running into an issue with a persisting part of the URL, let's call it `#x` that is used for navigation. I have an AuthenticationFilter on the server side that will redirect users to a login page. The issue is that I can't get this `#x` to go away. On the server side when I step through the Java code that does the redirect, I see the URL as `/login?redirectUrl=%2Fprevious%2Flocation`. However, on the client side this is actually `/login?redirectUrl=%2Fprevious%2Flocation#x`. I understand that this data is actually never sent to the server. My question is **how do I force the server to tell the client to drop it**? Do I have to switch to client-side redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in a couple of questions like here - [URL hash is persisting between redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283395/url-hash-is-persisting-between-redirects/). I ended up doing a client-side redirect to avoid the issue.

Comment: If you send a different `#bookmark` in your `302 redirect` then the browser may use that instead. See the second answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are never sent to server. So if you request an url like
example.org/my-account-overview#profile
the server only gets as requested resource the url
example.org/my-account-overview

If you send a redirect instead the browser should request the new url and adds the hash and the value after tha hash itself and automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Odds are that some javascript on your browser side is actually adding that `#x`, you'll need to fix that on the browser side.

To verify this, use the browser inspection tools + the network tab to see the actual request + response headers that are being sent both by the browser and the server.

If the server sends something like a `302 Redirect` its response `Location` header will contain the URI that it wants the browser to use.  If that URI doesn't contain the `#x` then you know that something on the browser itself is adding the `#x`.

While it is possible for a server to send the `#x` in its `Location` response header, the browser will never send this back to the server.