# Remove # and #_=_ from returning social auth url - Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am using python-social-auth and django in my authentication system.

At the moment, when I authenticate with either Facebook or Google, the URL returns with either `/#_=_` or `/#` appended. I understand that these are deliberate but I'd like to remove them.

I've seen a number of javascript solutions for the facebook version, but I'd like to do this from the server side.

I tried to do a basic redirect:

```
def pre_home(request):
   return redirect(reverse('home'))

def home(request):
   return render(request, 'core/home.html)
```

where I directed the auth system to `pre_home` on completion. I assumed this would strip off the end of the url on redirection to `home`, however it does not...

Comment: It's the browser that is persisting the hash, not the server. All you can do on the server is replace the anchor with an empty one, e.g. `return redirect(reverse('home'))+'#' `. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283395/url-hash-is-persisting-between-redirects).

Comment: OK - is there no way to force the browser to refresh without the # somehow?