# redirect is keeping hash

Tags: php, .htaccess, hash

For some reason when I redirect with `header("Location")` the new page keeps the hash.

So if you're on `example.com/index.html#signup`

I redirect with

```
header("Location: /account.html");
exit;
```

But then it shows `example.com/account.html#signup`

Why is this happening and how can I stop it? ie `example.com/account.html`

---

Note:

I am using an .htaccess to redirect `file.html` to `file.php`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer to "how do I stop it" is to specify an empty hash in the `Location` header:

```
header('Location: /account.html#');
```

However, this behavior isn't guaranteed across the board.  It seems to work in WebKit and IE9 in my quick test.  Nevertheless, you've stumbled on a [black hole in the HTTP specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects).

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking around for answer that works on Firefox. After a while surfing here and there while my cat is keeping meow meow, it leads me to the final solution:

`die('<script> window.location='your-url-without-hash';</script>');`

Sometimes you want to reserve the hash, sometimes you don't, and because the cross-browser matters so it's better to control client browser to reload and kill the hash.