# Remove Fragment Identifier on 302 Redirect

Tags: zend-framework, fragment-identifier, http-redirect

I have a page with a form at the bottom. I use a fragment identifier in the form action, because the form re-displays on post when there are errors, and I don't want the user to have to scroll down to it to make corrections.

When the form is successfully processed, I perform a redirect to the same page and display a confirmation message. The problem I am having is that the browser [preserves the fragment identifier upon 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects). Is there a trick to force the browser to clear/remove the fragment identifier?

---

Let's say I'm looking at a user profile page, and there's an address form on the page. The form action would be `/user/profile#AddressForm`. If the form is submitted with errors, the page automatically is scrolled to the address form so the user can correct the errors. If there are no errors, I want to redirect to `/user/profile`, which doesn't have the fragment identifier. The problem I am running into is that the browser retains the fragment identifier and the page scrolls back down to the form, instead of staying at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Now that I see what is the actual problem I would suggest a redirect to non-existing anchor

```
header ('Location: /user/profile#top');
```

---

There is.

```
$form->setAction ($this->getRequest ()->getRequestUri ());
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue. I do not have a problem setting the form "action". I have a problem doing a redirect afterward, because the browser is retaining the fragment identifier, and I want it to go away.

Comment: I think I do. Browser retains fragment identifier only when action attribute is not set. When action is explicitly set, it does not.

Comment: I always set the action. Either way, I am doing a redirect after post, so the form action is no longer a factor.

Comment: I thought that may be the only solution, but I wanted to confirm.