# Webview ignoring #(hash) argument on opening links in external browser

Tags: windows-8, webview, microsoft-metro

I have a `webview` in which I am rendering a html file containing a link (`anchor tag` with `target="_blank"` ) which will open in `external browser`. Here is the code for the html:

`"<html><body><a href='https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/?shva=1#sent' target='_blank'>Test</a></body></html>";`

On clicking the link, when it opens in the external browser, `the hash part is removed`. Why does this happen?

How can I prevent this or overcome this defect?

**UPDATE**

On further experimenting, I have found out that the external browser neglects the #fragment if the browser is not IE by default. (`Non-Metro`)

Comment: That part is formally called the "fragment identifier". Perhaps that helps searching for known issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a part of the standard, and then Again, it's not. Read this question to get a grasp at what you are facing :) [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)