# IE: Hash value removed in ReturnUrl

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have an asp.net mvc 3 application where I am using jquery tabs plugin in one of the authenticated pages. I have used localscroll plugin to update the url in the browser (by appending the hash value of the selected tab without refreshing the page) based on the tab selected by the user. I have to support the bookmark feature where if a user bookmarks the url, he should be taken to that tab(identified from the hash value) when he uses that bookmarked url.

When the user tries to access the bookmarked url next time without being authenticated, he is redirected to the login page with the return url being the bookmark url. As the hash value is not sent to the server, I am storing the hash value in client side from the return url and later on using that to redirect the user to the correct tab.

The problem is that Firefox and Chrome are having hash value in the return url after a 302 from the server but IE is not having hash value in the return url. Is there any way to get the hash value in case of IE in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer by referencing another SFO item:

> Safari 5 and IE9 and below drop the original URI's fragment if a HTTP/3xx redirect occurs. If the Location header on the response specifies a fragment, it is used.
>
> Chrome 11, Firefox 4, and Opera will all "reattach" the original URI's
>   fragment after following a 3xx redirection.
>
> Test page: https://www.fiddler2.com/test/redir/fragment/

Refer: [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)