# How can I get '#' symbol in a PHP header(Location: ) request

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi I'm trying to implement a simple contact form on my website using this tutorial - http://rosstanner.co.uk/2012/11/build-simple-contact-form-html-php-bootstrap/

Trouble is after the user submits an action I need the user to be redirected to an anchor ID down the bottom of the page i.e. www.somepage.com/index.php#contact

The redirect is this...

```
header('Location: index.php?s='.urlencode('Thank you for your message.'))
```

I've tried...

```
header('Location: index.php?s='.urlencode('Thank you for your message.')'#contact')
```

...but to no avail.

When I try to add anything like this to make it scroll down to the anchor bookmark the browser hangs on the contact-form-submission.php page (separate php page for the contact form logic)

I'm sorry if I've explained this in a convoluted. I don't actually know PHP!

Comment: You missed concatenation operator `.` before your '#contact' so the script fails. Maybe that's why browser hangs.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please use the search before asking a question. This website works by collecting common questions over time, not to add them over and over again.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the linked question. In the linked question the OP wants to read the current hash and mirror it in the new URL (which isn't possible). OP here doesn't care what the hash already was, he just wants to set a new one (which definitely is possible)

Comment: @Gareth: Yes, the better duplicate is this one: [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2286402/367456) .

Comment: I did do a search but I'm lost when it comes to PHP. I didn't understand the duplicate thread. Extra specificity in adding questions like these to the pool can help novices like me who don't know exactly what to search for.

Comment: @user2298352 Can you expand on what "the browser hangs" means? Do you get a white screen or what?

Comment: The browser went to the contact-form-submission.php page and the page failed to cease loading (yes, white page displayed)

Comment: BTW thanks Kamil and Jack, it was just the . operator I was missing before the '#contact'

Comment: white page = page of death: Please see [PHP Error Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) if you run into problems, it has good tips. (see first entry of the list ;)).

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax is this:

```
header('Location: index.php?s=' . urlencode('Thank you for your message.') . '#contact');
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks Jack.