# PHP Header: Location insists on copying over the "#section" portion of a URL

Tags: php, http, url, backbone.js

Let's say this is in a file called `index.php` at `http://mysite.com/`:

```
if ( !logged_in() ) {
    header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/login/");
}
```

If someone enters the url `http://mysite.com/#profile/edit/`, PHP copies the "#profile/edit/" over to the redirected address. Accordingly, the user is sent to: `mysite.com/login/#profile/edit/`. This is not the behaviour that I want. I simply want it to redirect to `mysite.com/login/`.

Does anyone know how to tell PHP to only use the location that I give it, and ignore any other information that it *thinks* it's supposed to use?

**EDIT:** The reason this comes up as an issue for me is that I'm using the routing system of `Backbone` (which relies on "#parms" for navigation).

**EDIT2:** Looks like PHP redirection just isn't safe when working with hashes, as the behaviour is not consistent across browsers. An alternative, of course, is to use a javascript-based solution instead:

```
function redirect(href) {
    // window.location.hash = ""; (not necessary)
    window.location = href;
}
```

However, this is a serious pain in the ass, as I now need PHP to tell javascript to do the redirection later on in the page. But, if I don't, when a user clicks on a bookmark (made when they were logged in) of `mysite.com/#profile/` it redirects them to `mysite.com/login/#profile/`, at which point they are told they've reached an invalid URL.

Ugh.

Comment: I've never seen that happen before...

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

Comment: @mario, That will still add a `#` to the mysite.com URL.

Comment: @mario That works for Chrome but not for FF

Comment: All in all, this has nothing to do with PHP, but HTTP/HTML and user agents.