# Android WebView removes everything after a # in the URL after a redirect

Tags: android, webview

Apparently everything after the hash is called "encoded fragment". The Uri.getEncodedFragment() returns this string.

My use case is this. Given an URL:

```
url = "https://first/#/second"
```

If I do a:

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

The WebView removes everything after the hash symbol, making the request with the modified URL:
"https://first/"

Any ideas on how to pass the full URL in the request?

**EDIT:**

I think this is related to a well known redirect problem:
[URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

Anyone has any solution for Android?

Comment: did you get any solution?