# Java response.sendRedirect() not clearing angularjs state providers url after #

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, servlets, angular-ui-router

Currently I am working in angular js and j2ee frameworks.

Currently I am http:something.com/home/#/main

But if i am redirect the above url from java servlet using response.sendRedirect("http:something.com/login/")

It redirects me to the page but in browsers url "#/main" remains even after redirecting like below....

http:something.com/login/#/main.

I don't want that angulars state after my redirection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prevailing browser behaviour is to [preserve URL fragments after redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects).
If the location in the redirect contains a URL fragment, then it will override any carried over URL fragment.

So what you could do is simply append an empty URL fragment (hash mark `#`) to your redirect so that it clears anything being carried over.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://something.com/login/#")
```