# Is it possible to send a Django HttpResponseRedirect but to a certain ID in the HTML page?

Tags: python, html, django, url, httpresponse

I have this simple view where the user confirms or declines an offer:

```
def confirmoffer(request, offerid):
    offer = Offer.objects.get(id = offerid)
    if 'confirm' in request.GET:

        offer.traveler_approval = True;
    else:
        offer.traveler_approval = False;
    offer.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard#excursionoffers/")
```

I'm trying to return the user to her dashboard but to a certain part instead of the begining of the page thus I did this: `dashboard#excursionoffers/` however a slash gets automatically added to look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/#excursionoffers/
```

Which renders the id with no effect.

That's the url for the dashboard:

```
url(r'^dashboard/$', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `urls.py`, you may have added this `dashboard/$`.

Remove slash at the end to make it look like `dashboard$`. It may help

Comment: Alternatively, keep the slash in the url, and redirect to `/dashboard/#excursionoffers`