# Rewrite urls which contains /#!

Tags: redirect

I want o redirect http://www.domainname.ae/#!/pageMore to http://www.domainname.ae/any-page/

due to containing #! part not redirecting

tried many ways not working

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite those URLs on a server? I believe anything after the # is not sent by the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)