url fragment is missed in post response
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
// create a stripe checkout session in express server
  ...
  res.redirect(303, session.url); 
// session.url looks like 'https://checkout.stripe.com/xyz#abc...'

// react frontend
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session", // nothing is wrong with this endpoint!
      {method: "POST"}
    );
console.log('response.url', response.url);
// This should be 'https://checkout.stripe.com/xyz#abc...', instead it gets 'https://checkout.stripe.com/xyz'

I don't understand why url fragment is missed from response of fetch post request, can anyone explain this please?

See this answer  (and the surrounding context of the question/other answers) https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915350/1086398. Its the way browsers handle this case. What are you wanting to do with that URL after you have it? If it is to send the user to that location, you should not be using fetch at all but just doing window.location.href = "http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session" instead

@adsy, Thank you for you answer, I know a way to fix this issue which is using res.json({url: session.url}}, then in client side, window.location.url = await response.json().url; however, I just don't understand why url fragment is not carried over to frontend when using res.redirect(303, response.url);

@adsy, by the way, window.location.href = "http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session" won't work because it is a post request endpoint"

Ah sorry ignore first comment. In short the fragment in the redirect is not actually used as part of the HTTP retrieval process itself.  Generally, fragments are not sent to a server when you hit a fragment URL. It is something that is held by the client and applied later. So that's why res.url does not have this, as res.url is the location on which the resource was fetched, which is subtly different from the Location response header on the redirect.

Since the browser itself handles the redirect, you can't actually access that Location header directly either. Its all opaque in userland by design. res.url has a slightly different semantic meaning. When the browser first sees the fragment on the 303, and it makes an internal req to the redirect target, the fragment is dropped at that point as it is never included  in a HTTP request URL in any context. The resulting response URL therefore also does not have it. If you hit say google.com/#test with your dev tools open, notice network req does not include fragment in uri.
